# ¿Cómo ejecutar un script de Python en el background en Linux Terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, raspberry-pi

Tengo un problema que no se como solucionar. Yo uso la Raspberry Pi en modo terminal para varios usos. Uno de ellos es para ejecutar un bot de Discord en Python. El problema es que cuando ejecuto el script, no puedo ejecutar más comandos en el prompt.

¿Alguien sabe como puedo ejecutarlo en segundo plano?

Muchas gracias y saludos :)

Comment: `comando &`. La [documentación de Bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) es un buen lugar para empezar. Y [esta publicación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4884/19610) también.

Comment: @Trauma. La documentación de Bash es indigerible: +6.000 líneas de texto continuo sin ninguna estructura aparente, sin un índice ni una tabla de contenidos. La explicación del "&" que necesita el usuario aparece en la línea 2.700, perdida entre otras varias interpretaciones: metacharacter, control operator, bitwise AND, pathname expansion, and modifier for history expansion.

Comment: @CandidMoe Vale, tienes razón. No es el mejor lugar para empezar. Pero info sobre el tema hay *a patadas*; no creo que esta pregunta aporte gran cosa al sitio. Y me remito al 2º enlace que puse.

Comment: @Trauma. Sin embargo, creo que el tema de fondo (hacer un `daemon` en Python) es meritorio: la solución depende de la plataforma y ocupa comandos que no son de uso habitual.

Comment: @CandidMoe ... ummmm ... vale, lo dices por lo de `bot de Discord`. Buen punto. Pero requiere una buena edición. Ni por el título ni por el contenido se llegará a esta pregunta buscando información sobre ese tema. Pero insisto en que lo de `intento previo` brilla por su ausencia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hagamos un "bot" supersimple, que se limita a escribir una línea con un contador en un archivo local:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time

with open("datos.txt", "a") as arch:
    contador = 0
    while True:
        contador += 1
        print(f"Contador={contador}")
        arch.write(f"Contador={contador}\n")
        arch.flush()
        time.sleep(5)
```

He abierto el archivo en modo `append`, de modo que sucesivas ejecuciones no borren el contenido de las anteriores.

En cada iteración del `while` grabo una línea con el valor del contador y ejecuto un `flush` para forzar la grabación inmediata de la línea.

También imprimo una línea con la misma información. Está línea aparecería en pantalla en una ejecución normal, pero luego veremos que el resultado va a parar a un archivo (útil para depuración).

Finalmente, con `sleep` espero un tiempo antes de repetir el proceso.

**Convertir el script en ejecutable**

La primera línea del script debe ser el *shebang*, el path completo al programa que ejecutara el script. En este caso, el programa es Python3. Esta línea es leida por Bash para determinar como ejecutar el script.

Luego tienes que convertir el script (que aqui llame scratch.py) en un ejecutable:

```
candid@gear>chmod a+x scratch.py
```

Con eso todo el mundo puede ejecutarlo. Puedes revisarlo con `ls`

```
candid@gear>ls -lh scratch.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 candid candid 213 Oct 20 17:27 scratch.py
```

**Ejecutar el script**

Ejecuta esta línea:

```
nohup ./scratch.py &
```

Nota: Suponiendo que scratch.py está en el directorio actual. Si está en otra parte, hay que ajustar el path de la llamada.

El comando retorna dos líneas:

```
candid@gear:~/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.2/scratches$ nohup ./scratch.py &
[1] 79643
candid@gear:~/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.2/scratches$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

La primera línea te da el `id` del ejecutable. Puedes revisar su estado con `ps`

```
candid@gear>ps 79643
    PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
  79643 pts/2    S      0:00 /usr/bin/python3 ./scratch.py
```

Puedes usar el `id` para otros comandos, como `kill -TERM 79643`, con lo que matas el proceso.

**nohup y &**

Cuando terminas un comando con `&`, lo estas mandando a ejecutar al background, dejando libre el terminal. El detalle es que si cierras el terminal, o das logout, el comando (el script, en este caso) termina.

Si quieres que tu comando quede corriendo por siempre, incluso si cierras el terminal, usas `nohup`.

`nohup` genera un archivo, `nohup.out`, a donde van a parar los `print` del script. Ojo, que las lineas no aparecen de inmediato en el archivo; sólo se graba cuando se llena el buffer de salida.

**Revisión**

El script va generando líneas, que puedes revisar con usando `more`, `tail` o algun otro comando de tu preferencia.

```
candid@gear:~/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.2/scratches$ more datos.txt
Contador=1
Contador=2
Contador=3
Contador=4
Contador=5
Contador=6
```